# Use customization buffer to supply arguments to a function

Tags: emacs, customization, interactive

I need to call a function interactively with a lot of arguments (it is 7 at the moment, but it will grow). Reading all the arguments in succession creates bad experience. For example, I am asking a user to input a class name. The class name can be fully qualified by the package it is in or not. So if a user thinks it must be fully qualified, and then I later ask them to provide the package name, there's no way for the user to go back and fix the error.

There are also many aspects of the input that are difficult to take care of at once. For instance, I need to make sure that certain characters don't appear in a certain pattern in the string being read etc. If the input fails validation on the last item of the input, it will feel frustrating for users to restart the whole procedure, while if I had a customization buffer at my disposal I could simply prevent them from committing the change if it doesn't validate and keep the already submitted good values.

tl;dr

I'm looking for a way to open customization buffer and read the user input into a function that is called interactively. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the Emacs Widget Library instead of the customization buffer itself. Emacs info has an excellent section on the Widget Library. You can access it from emacs using `C-h i m Widget RET`. Or you can access the HTML version [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html). Here is the snippet of the widget example from the manual.

```elisp
 (require 'widget)

 (eval-when-compile
   (require 'wid-edit))

 (defvar widget-example-repeat)

 (defun widget-example ()
   "Create the widgets from the Widget manual."
   (interactive)
   (switch-to-buffer "*Widget Example*")
   (kill-all-local-variables)
   (make-local-variable 'widget-example-repeat)
   (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
     (erase-buffer))
   (remove-overlays)
   (widget-insert "Here is some documentation.\n\n")
   (widget-create 'editable-field
         :size 13
         :format "Name: %v " ; Text after the field!
         "My Name")
   (widget-create 'menu-choice
         :tag "Choose"
         :value "This"
         :help-echo "Choose me, please!"
         :notify (lambda (widget &rest ignore)
               (message "%s is a good choice!"
                    (widget-value widget)))
         '(item :tag "This option" :value "This")
         '(choice-item "That option")
         '(editable-field :menu-tag "No option" "Thus option"))
   (widget-create 'editable-field
         :format "Address: %v"
         "Some Place\nIn some City\nSome country.")
   (widget-insert "\nSee also ")
   (widget-create 'link
         :notify (lambda (&rest ignore)
               (widget-value-set widget-example-repeat
                         '("En" "To" "Tre"))
               (widget-setup))
         "other work")
   (widget-insert
     " for more information.\n\nNumbers: count to three below\n")
   (setq widget-example-repeat
    (widget-create 'editable-list
               :entry-format "%i %d %v"
               :notify (lambda (widget &rest ignore)
                 (let ((old (widget-get widget
                            ':example-length))
                       (new (length (widget-value widget))))
                   (unless (eq old new)
                     (widget-put widget ':example-length new)
                     (message "You can count to %d." new))))
               :value '("One" "Eh, two?" "Five!")
               '(editable-field :value "three")))
   (widget-insert "\n\nSelect multiple:\n\n")
   (widget-create 'checkbox t)
   (widget-insert " This\n")
   (widget-create 'checkbox nil)
   (widget-insert " That\n")
   (widget-create 'checkbox
         :notify (lambda (&rest ignore) (message "Tickle"))
         t)
   (widget-insert " Thus\n\nSelect one:\n\n")
   (widget-create 'radio-button-choice
         :value "One"
         :notify (lambda (widget &rest ignore)
               (message "You selected %s"
                    (widget-value widget)))
         '(item "One") '(item "Another One.") '(item "A Final One."))
   (widget-insert "\n")
   (widget-create 'push-button
         :notify (lambda (&rest ignore)
               (if (= (length (widget-value widget-example-repeat))
                  3)
                   (message "Congratulation!")
                 (error "Three was the count!")))
         "Apply Form")
   (widget-insert " ")
   (widget-create 'push-button
         :notify (lambda (&rest ignore)
               (widget-example))
         "Reset Form")
   (widget-insert "\n")
   (use-local-map widget-keymap)
   (widget-setup))
```